# Filtering Collection of images through jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have built a `DOM` with a for each loop to create a list of images like so:

```
@foreach ($imageAsString as $key=>$image) 
<li> <div id="{{$key}}" class="thumbnail"><a href="#"><img data-size="1.1" src="data:image/png;  base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image); ?>" alt="image1"/></a>
        </div></li>  
        @endforeach
```

The images are received as an array from PHP, using `Laravel 3` framework.
The original file name of the images is used as the key and the value is used to present the image.

Now what I'm trying to do is filter these images based on a link that is clicked to display only the images pertaining to the clicked link (based on order #) like so:

HTML->

```
<li id="order-id" class="folders"> <a href="#">Folders</a>
@foreach($orders_cloud as $order)
    <ul id ="orders">
        <li value="{{$order}}" data-rel="{{$order}}" id="{{$order}}">
            <a href="#" value="{{$order}}">
                <span class="number"></span>
                Order #{{ $order }}
            </a>
        </li>
```

JS->

```
    $('#orders li').click(function() {

    var order = $(this).attr('value');

    $('.column2 .title h2').text('Order #' + order).show();

        $('.column2 .list1 .thumbnail').filter(function() {
   $(this).attr('id').match(/^order/)
        }).show();
    return false;
});
```

Question: What is the correct way to filter this content so that only the images that start with order#_ are displayed upon clicking the order # link (without re-loading the page).

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <div id="14179_low_folder001_00006a.jpg" class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
            <img data-size="1.1" id="14179_low_folder001_00006a.jpg"
                    src="data:image/png;base64,/" alt="image1"/>
        </a> 
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="inner"> 
                <span class="checkbox"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" /> 
                </span> 
            </div>
        </div> 
        <span class="checkbox">
            &nbsp;
        </span> 
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use this selector

```
$('.column2 .list1 .thumbnail[id^='+ order + '\\#]')
```

The `var order` has to be appended to the selector as you want to replace that with the value of currently selected item.

**JS**

```
$('#orders li').click(function () {

    var order = $(this).attr('value');

    $('.column2 .title h2').text('Order #' + order).show();

    $('.column2 .list1 .thumbnail[id^='+ order + '\\#]').show();

    return false;
});
```

Also if you want to use the Regex

```
.match(/^order/)
```

supposed to be

```
.match(new Regex("^" + order));
```

Comment: Oops... `thumbnail` is the class for the images right.,. Check updated code.. The previous version was searching for images inside `thumbnail` class.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't change any of the displayed images.

Comment: Could you explain the [id^='+ order + '\\#]' part of the code?

Comment: I'm a beginner with regex - is this syntax checking for names/values that start with the variable order, or must equal order?

Comment: It Matches beginning of input.

Comment: Can you show the sample `HTML` that is rendered so that I can get you the right selector.. Looks like the selector is not correct in the first place

Comment: <li> <div id="14179_low_folder001_00006a.jpg" class="thumbnail"><a href="#"><img data-size="1.1" id="14179_low_folder001_00006a.jpg" src="data:image/png;base64,/" alt="image1"/></a>
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="inner"> <span class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                </span> </div>
            </div>
            <span class="checkbox">&nbsp;</span>
            </div></li>

Comment: @egekhter.. I don't any element with `attribute value`in the `HTML`.. `var order = $(this).attr('value');.. I wanted the HTML that contains all the elements in the code that you have written
`

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value that filters the objects:

```
$('.column2 .list1 .thumbnail').filter(function() {
    return this.id.indexOf(order) === 0;
}).show();
```

Also, `value` is not a valid attribute for `<a>` and `<li>` elements. If you absolutely *must* store this data in the HTML, use `data-` attributes:

```
data-order="foo"
```

And fetch it with `.data()`:

```
var order = $(this).data('order');
```

Comment: I've updated the code to change value to data.
I tried out your method and it works when I change show() to hide() and it removes the elements. But when I leave it as show() nothing changes.

Comment: @egekhter: You need to come up with a better HTML structure. Consider writing the ordering data as a plain JavaScript object with JSON.

Comment: I tried converting the array to json but upon adding it the script freezes the browser. I'm assuming this is because the encoded image data is a lot of characters per image.

Comment: I'm not familiar with encoding URLs.

Comment: @egekhter: Instead of encoding the image (base64?), just send the URL to the image.